# Using MySql INET_NTOA / INET_ATON functions in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ip-address, entity-framework-6

I want to store IPv4 addresses in a MySQL DB and I'm not sure whether to use VARCHAR(15) or UNSIGNED INT as the column type. That DB will be accessed using C# (ASP.NET MVC) and EF6.

I don't really care about the space savings benefit USINGED INT offers vs VARCHAR(15), and performance wise they should be on par except when comparing IP ranges where USINGED INT and bit wise operations should be faster than string comparisons.

If I was to use UNSIGNED INT I would need to call INET_NTOA / INET_ATON functions all the time in my EF model. What is the suggested way of using INET_NTOA and INET_ATON from EF6? Or do I have to write an equivalent C# code? I searched Google up and down and couldn't find suggestions for this problem.

Also, if I would use UNSIGNED INT, how would I implement searching / filtering in my EF model?